# Can't receive notifications any more, Android with GCM

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Messaging in one my android applications, everything was going fine but once I changed the package structure of my project I couldn't receive notifications , here is my new Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gcm"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gcm.actvities.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

            <receiver
        android:name="com.example.gcm.utils.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.example.gcm.services.GCMNotificationIntentService" />

</application>
```

Comment: Please check your API key, is it registered with the same package name as u r using as changed package. Also, check your device id, the notification being sent to correct device id or is it being sent to older i.e.  because of change u made it got changed?

Comment: In fact i have tested my app on another mobile and it worked , but still not working on my phone and other phones, what do you think the issue is ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the code of `com.example.gcm.utils.GcmBroadcastReceiver`, but since your trouble started after changing packages, it is very likely that the code of the broadcast receiver that starts the intent service uses `context.getPackageName()` as the package of the intent service, which is incorrect after your change. You should specify the correct package of the intent service class.

Assuming you used the standard code from the GCM demo in your receiver, it probably look like this :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

In that case, change it to this :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(GcmIntentService.class.getPackage().getName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

Comment: still nothing , i've tried the code with the context.getPackageName() and it worked on other mobile and it worked fine same as GcmIntentService.class.getPackage().getName() but both codes not working on my phone

Comment: @ZouhairElamraniAbouElassad What Android versions are the phone where it doesn't work and and phone where it works?

Comment: it works on Adnroid 4.1.2 and is still not working on Android 4.0.4 but it used to

Comment: i made a reboot to the phone that used to work , now it's not working also but other application still receive notifications , now i'm confused

Comment: @ZouhairElamraniAbouElassad I'm confused too. Can you explain what exactly you changed in the package structure? Did you change the main package of the app? Can you post the broadcast receiver code?

Comment: sorry it took me this long to answer , in fact my onReceive code is the same as above , but now i changed the GcmIntentService.class.getPackage() to context.getPackageName() again and it worked on the phone again , butt still not working on my phone , no notifications works an my phone any more

Comment: OK now things getting better , i started to receive notifications on my phone but from another app , so i think there is a problem with reg id generated from the app